# NSLog not executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I made a test app for taking photos using a camera button. I'm testing on a simulator, so i cannot take snapshots. But i have created an IBAction method which when called, allows the user to select a pic from the photo library. 
This is the method:-

```
   - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
            NSLog(@"Camera button tapped");
           UIImagePickerController *imagePicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
              if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])   {
                  NSLog(@"Yes. The Camera is available");
                  [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

               }
               else{
                 NSLog(@"The Camera isn't available. Try thru the Photo Library");
                [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
               }
            imagePicker.allowsEditing=YES;
            [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

            NSLog(@"Presenting Modal Controller");
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

         }
```

In the above scenario, when the method is called (that is when i tap the camera bar button item),the console does not log **Camera button tapped** message as well as **Presenting Modal Controller** message.All the other appropriate NSLog messages are being logged as they should be.
 I don't understand how come the runtime not execute these NSLog lines.
There's a similar problem in **-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info** that i face.
Here's the implementation—

```
     -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
           NSLog(@"imagePicker called");
           NSString *oldKey= _item.imageKey;
           if (oldKey) {
              NSLog(@"Deleting image having key- %@",oldKey);
              [[BNRImageStore sharedStore] deleteImageForKey:oldKey];
           }

          UIImage *image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

          CFUUIDRef newUniqueID= CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
          CFStringRef newUniqueIDString= CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);

          //Use that uniqueID to set our item's imageKey
          NSString *key= (__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIDString;
          _item.imageKey=key;

          //Store image in the BNRImageStore with this key
          NSLog(@"putting %@ in dictionary table",_item.imageKey);
          [[BNRImageStore sharedStore] setImage:image forKey:_item.imageKey];

          //Releasing Core-Foundation objects
           CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
           CFRelease(newUniqueID);

           [imageView setImage:image];
           NSLog(@"Dismissing Modal Controller");
           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   }
```

Here. the NSLog messages— **imagePicker called** and in the third last line— **Dismissing Modal Controller** are not showing up in the console. Again the runtime doesnt process these NSLog lines.

Am i assuming something wrong, because this behavior is so very weird. What's happening?

Comment: This sounds like a derived data problem. Try deleting your derived data and doing a clean build

Comment: What exactly is a derived data??

Comment: Is it safe to delete contents of that specific folder?? What will it do?

Comment: other than NSLog .. is your app functionality working fine? few statements like NSLog (in editoe), PO(Console), P(Console) will not work some time, some time these will show wrong values also. functionality is working fine then try to show alert instead of NSLog and check.

Comment: Derived data is the indexed information for your project. Deleting it forces XCode to reindex your project.

Comment: @JamesWebster So there are a ton of folders inside of DerivedData that are organized as data based on the projects that i have been creating. So should i select the particular project data folder and trash it or wipe out all other contents as well i.e everything inside of DerivedData??

Comment: @CharanGiri Well what kind of alert are u talking about??..Are u saying use a breakpoint to check the execution flow? And yeah, my app's functionality is working fine. The IBAction method gets called as i trigger the camera bar button event. When the modal view is brought up and i select a pic from there, it dismisses and i'm back at my original view. The delegate method for modal view is executed during this process. But again the two NSLogs in there do not run as well...

Comment: Use ALog once and check and let me know

Comment: Yes I'd suggest deleting the relevant project(s)

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of code below:-

```
#define NSLog if(0) NSLog
```

If it is mention 0 then your nslog statement will not execute. So make it 1 and check

```
#define NSLog if(1) NSLog
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 other than NSLog .. is your app functionality working fine? few statements like NSLog (in   editoe), PO(Console), P(Console) will not work some time, some time these will show wrong values also. functionality is working fine then try to show alert instead of NSLog and check.
```

Try using the instead of NSLog and check.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ALog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"\n\n************************ DEBUG ***********************\n Class&method: %@,\n Line of Code: %d\n element Info: %@\n******************************************************************\n\n",  \
```

[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:**FUNCTION**] lastPathComponent], **LINE**, \
[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##**VA_ARGS**] );

#else
   #define ALog(...)
   #endif

use just like NSLog  ex: ALog(@"log is placed");